# Why does flutter app always crash after debugging

Tags: laravel, flutter

this is the main.dart file if there is anyone can help me. after crashing it stuck on this message :

```
Launching lib\\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 arm in debug mode...

lib\\main.dart:1

√  Built build\\app\\outputs\\flutter-apk\\app-debug.apk.
```

like this

[image]

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';

class BaseUrl {
  static String url = 'https://awad.mohatim.tech/public/api';
  static String real = 'https://awad.mohatim.tech/api/';
  static String local = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/';
}

Map<String, String> headers = {
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
};

class DioHelper {
  static final BaseOptions _options = BaseOptions(
    baseUrl: BaseUrl.real,
    headers: headers,
    validateStatus: (status) {
      return status! < 500;
    },
  );

  static final Dio _dio = Dio(_options);

  // get login #  data  = email and password
  static Future getLogin({required Map<String, dynamic> data}) async {
    try {
      Response response = await _dio.post('login', data: data);
      return response;
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      print(e.message);
    }
  }

  // data  = name email phone paswword
  static Future register({required Map<String, dynamic> data}) async {
    try {
      Response response = await _dio.post('register', data: data);
      return response;
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      print(e.message);
    }
  }

// public request

  static Future post({required String endpoint, required dynamic data}) async {
    Map<String, String> headers = {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    };
    try {
      Response response = await _dio.post(endpoint, data: data, options: Options(headers: headers));
      return response;
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      print(e.message);
    }
  }

// public request
  static Future get({required String endpoint}) async {
    try {
      Response response = await _dio.get(endpoint);
      return response;
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      print(e.message);
    }
  }

  static Future getWithToken({required String endpoint, required String token}) async {
    Map<String, String> headers = {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
    };

    try {
      Response response = await _dio.get(endpoint, options: Options(headers: headers));
      return response;
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      print(e.message);
    }
  }

  static Future postWithToken({required String endpoint, required dynamic data, required String token}) async {
    Map<String, String> headers = {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
    };
    try {
      Response response = await _dio.post(endpoint, data: data, options: Options(headers: headers));
      return response;
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      print(e.message);
    }
  }

  static Future postImage({required String endpoint, required FormData data, required String token}) async {
    Map<String, String> headers = {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
    };

    try {
      Response response = await _dio.post(endpoint, data: data, options: Options(headers: headers));
      return response;
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      print(e.message);
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to connect the app with Laravel admin panel throw API

Comment: post the crash stacktrace

Comment: where I can find that ?? @MarcinOrlowski

Comment: connect you phone to the computer, launch AS (I assume this is what you use to develop), switch to LogCat view and make the crash.

Comment: I'm using vc @MarcinOrlowski

Comment: you mean visualstudio code? then you need to check how to view so called "logcat" in that IDE. I see there are [some plugins for that](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=logcat&target=VSCode&category=Other&sortBy=Relevance) as well. Or you can use [logcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat) tool.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski it doesn't show anything i start capture it but nothing recorded when I tried to debug the app again .. is there is another way ??

Comment: logcat always contains something. if not from your app then from others or from system etc. So if you see nothing you should try to figure out why because you definitely should see something

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski is there is another way ?? without using logcat

Comment: You actually want to check the crash stracktrace as this is often useful to nail the culprit

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski

E/AndroidRuntime(25654): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(25654): Process: com.moha.muntijuh_app, PID: 25654
E/AndroidRuntime(25654): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.moha.muntijuh_app/com.moha.muntijuh_app.MainActivity}

Comment: Please edit the question and paste *whole* stacktrace there. It's hard to read it in comment (plus looks incomplete)